# How to add time (ticks) in a GUI for a game

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to add the ticking of time in seconds to a GUI, for a clicker game. So the idea is to have a function that gets called every n ticks, and this function increments X objects.

I have tried to use a while loop, both before and after calling the .mainloop() method. It didn't work in either occasion, I also tried the crazy idea of having the mainloop() method inside the while loop (aware of what that would do lol).

```
from tkinter import *
import time
result = 0

window = Tk()
window.title("Numbers Game")
window.geometry('360x240')

label = Label(window, text=result)
label.grid(column=0,row=0)

def clicked():
    global result
    result += 1
    label.config(text=result)

button = Button(window, text="Push Me", command=clicked)
button.grid(column=1, row=2)

window.mainloop()

while True:
time.sleep(1)
clicked()
```

The current version of my code produces an error that mentions the function doing GUI related things outside of the window. But I don't have the slightest clue of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you want to have the result counter increment every second? You can't use infinite loops with a GUI, because they interfere with the GUI's mainloop. You have to integrate your code into the mainloop using the `after` method.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
result = 0

window = Tk()
window.title("Numbers Game")
window.geometry('360x240')

label = Label(window, text=result)
label.grid(column=0,row=0)

def clicked():
    global result
    result += 1
    label.config(text=result)

def tick():
    clicked()
    window.after(1000, tick) # after 1,000 milliseconds, call tick() again

button = Button(window, text="Push Me", command=clicked)
button.grid(column=1, row=2)

tick() # start the "loop"
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: So, basically, placing a function just like that at the end would (not literally) start a sort of loop? Or is that done by the after() method?

Comment: @Dan, right. It starts a loop, but in python "loop" generally means a `for` or `while` loop, and it's neither of those. The second to last line calls the function, and at the end of the function it schedules itself to be called again in 1 second. This repeats forever.

Comment: great solution. The method invokation isn’t even recursive